# Post data not populating the model as expected

Tags: asp.net, ajax, asp.net-web-api

I have a web form that submits an ajax request to one of my controllers. The request looks like the following:

Parsed

```
CustomerId:2937
models:{"OriginalDate":"2015-08-12T17:06:37.25","BatteryName":"Briggs B-2H and 3H Water Tank","DeviceName":"Briggs B2-B3 - Water Tank 5","Date":"2015-08-11T22:06:00.000Z"}
```

Raw

```
CustomerId=2937&models=%7B%22OriginalDate%22%3A%222015-08-12T17%3A06%3A37.25%22%2C%22BatteryName%22%3A%22Briggs+B-2H+and+3H+Water+Tank%22%2C%22DeviceName%22%3A%22Briggs+B2-B3+-+Water+Tank+5%22%2C%22Date%22%3A%222015-08-11T22%3A06%3A00.000Z%22%7D
```

My controller method looks like:

```
    [Route("Update")]
    [HttpPost]
    public IHttpActionResult Update(UpdateQuery model)
    {
        try
        {
            ...
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return InternalServerError(ex);
        }
    }

    public class UpdateQuery
    {
        public int CustomerId { get; set; }
        public EventModel models { get; set; }
    }

    public class EventModel
    {
        public string OriginalDate { get; set; }
        public string BatteryName { get; set; }
        public string DeviceName { get; set; }
        public string Date { get; set; }
    }
```

When the request comes in, the CustomerId field gets populated without any issues, but the "models" portion does not.

What could be causing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should work if you send a valid JSON like this.

```
{
    "CustomerId": "2937",
    "models": {
        "OriginalDate": "2015-08-12T17:06:37.25",
        "BatteryName": "Briggs B-2H and 3H Water Tank",
        "DeviceName": "Briggs B2-B3 - Water Tank 5",
        "Date": "2015-08-11T22:06:00.000Z"
    }
}
```

The Web api model binding will convert this Json structure to your model, an instance of `UpdateQuery`.

Sample code to build this JSON structure and send to the endpoint using jQuery

```
var data = {models : {}};
data.CustomerId = 234233;
data.models.OriginalDate = "2015-08-12T17:06:37.25";
data.models.BatteryName = "Briggs B-2H and 3H Water Tank";
data.models.DeviceName = "Briggs B2-B3 - Water Tank 5";
data.models.Date = "2015-08-11T22:06:00.000Z";


$.post(yourApiEndPointUrlHere, data, function(res) {
    console.log(res);
});
```

Comment: Looks like you were spot on.